# Screen size in pixels (iPhone 6)

Tags: iphone

According to the page here: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions the iPhone 6 screen size in pixels should be 750×1334 (1334x750 landscape) however my application seems to think the screen dimensions are 667/375 in landscape and it's not being rendered properly to the entire screen. Here's the code I'm using to get the window dimensions when the application launches as well as opengl.

applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenW = rect.size.width;
CGFloat screenH = rect.size.height;
```

initGL:

```
CGRect rect = [glView bounds];
CGFloat screenW = rect.size.width;
CGFloat screenH = rect.size.height;
glOrthof(0, screenW, 0, screenH, -1, 1);
```

Both functions print out the same values: 667w/375h. Could this have to do with an issue I had with the splash image, where basically I had to rename it from `Default-667h@2x.png` to `Default-375w-667h@2x.png` to get it to load properly? I feel like this is something simple I'm missing here, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is is ok. What you see is logical points. These get translated into physical pixels. In case of iPhone 6 it is 2x.

Comment: Okay, so when drawing to the screen, I should be using points and not pixels? I've hard coded most of the drawing against the old iPhone screen dimensions, so simply changing the instances of 480/320 to the `point` values of the iPhone 6 sizes should resolve this? If so, I have another question. How would I then render with other screen sizes? Let's say I have users on iPhone 3G, 4, 5, 6, and 6+. Do I have to have different drawing code for each set of point values?

Comment: Always reason with points in your code.
Regarding bitmaps, you need to provide a separate set for old iphone (3GS), and 2x and 3x versions for newer ones incl. iphone6+.
If you are creating visuals using via CGGraphics or simple UIView configuration, then you will get it rendered to crisp pixels for free.

Comment: Later I will try replacing all of the hardcoded screen dimensions with the values provided by `glView bounds` and `UIScreen bounds` and see if that resolves the error, I was just worried that they were providing incorrect values. I will post back if I have any more questions, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking one more quick question, are my methods to getting the full screen size perfectly valid? I think I've had a few issues with the dimensions returned with this code before, so if there is a better way I'd definitely be interested :)

Comment: No, that's the correct way for years and it is still valid.